# Line with round endings

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, line-art

I want to do a line with rounded endings in Photoshop:

[image]

[This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/45784/54008) gives a partial solution. But when adding a line + a circle, the shades are *slightly* different for the circle and the line, resulting in an amateurish result:

[image]

I tried to increase/reduce the radius of the circle of a few pixels, but it doesn't change anything.

**Is there a cleaner solution to do lines with round endings with Phothoshop (CS5)?**

*If not possible at all, how to do it, at least with Illustrator?*

Comment: Is this a simplified example? Could you use [`Rounded rectangle tool`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bDSO.gif)?

Comment: @Joonas I spent almost 2 hours on this problem, if I put all the attempts together, so +10000 ! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Joonas: how to do it with a constant thickness, let's say always 15px? When I use rounded rectangle tool, I have to drag the mouse to set the width... It's difficult to find a precise width of 15px. And if I do Transform after, I can move to 15px, but the rounded end won't be a circle anymore...

Comment: Try clicking the document once and you should be able to insert width and height there. Also, you could also use [`Direct selection tool`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Rrw.gif) to make a selection of one half of the rounded rectangle and move all the selected points pixel by pixel with the arrow keys.

Comment: @Joonas `Try clicking the doc once...` : I couldn't make it work. Do you have more info?   `Direct selection tool + move all selected points` : it transforms the ending-circle into something which is not a circle anymore

Comment: So in versions prior to cs6, you should find the size option [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neeoS.png). This screenshot was taken with cs3. This same window-panel thing also exists in version cs6 and later, though it's behind a cogwheel icon.

Comment: Wonderful @Joonas ! You could (should ;)) put all these things together (the helpful screenshots) in an answer, and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2):

@Basj, I think @Joonas was directing you to click the document once **while the Rounded Rectangle Tool is selected**. It will bring up a dialog box that allows you to choose the object's dimensions:

[image]

Then if you click the artboard again, the last-used dimensions will already be populated in the dialog box (even if you have clicked/used other tools since then).

(Don't want to steal the credit for Joonas' answer, but I couldn't post a screenshot in the comments)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I click once the document (even once Rounded rectangle selected), nothing happens. I cannot get this dialogbox. I'm using Photoshop CS5. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, that's why... the instructions I gave are for Illustrator, I don't know that Photoshop CS5 has that option... I'm using PS CC2015.5, and it does give me the dialog box, but I don't remember if CS5 does. 
I'm pretty sure it'll still work in Illustrator CS5 though.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop CS6 or newer...

Alter the **Stroke Options**, and adjust the `Caps` for any path, located in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen after drawing a path....

[image]

Set the Caps to rounded, as shown above, and you should be done.